# Reduce height of mat-flat-button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a message board that I want to add delete buttons to, unfortunately the mat-flat-button seems to be doubling the height of the message items. If i set it's height to 50%, the button becomes half the height of the message box, which will itself remain double the height as for without the button.

Without button:
[image]

With Button:
[image]

Any tips on getting the button to inherit the height of the container it resides within?

Comment: FYI [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/). Next time please tag accordingly.

Comment: Ahh apologies! must have been typing too quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix, setting the `line-height` property to inherit in my css has resolved it